# Puppet File_Line resource always triggering a refresh each time

Tags: puppet

I am modifying a file utilizing puppet file_line resource but each time puppet runs, its triggering a refresh even though no other change has been made after the first puppet run.

```
file_line { 'log_format_combined':
   ensure            => present,
   path              => '/etc/apache2/apache2.conf',
   line              => 'LogFormat "%a %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined',
   match             => '^LogFormat "%h %l %u %t ."%r." %>s %b ."%{Referer}i." ."%{User-Agent}i."" combined',
}
```

What can I do to only trigger a refresh if a change is made to the file?

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and it works perfectly, and the file_line makes sure the code is executed only once if no change has made.

So when I run puppet for the first time I get this

```
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Node[default]/File_line[log_format_combined]/ensure: created
```

and then nothing when I run the puppet agent again.

Are you sure your file hasn't changed after the puppet agent run ? don't you have another puppet resource that change that file ?

Comment: B, well, I have an apache puppet module that manages that file. When I run puppet I get ```-LogFormat "%a %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined``` and ```+LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined``` but when i check the file, it still has +LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined which is what I want in there. I am using the file_line resource to avoid making the change directly in the apache module. It's a little misleading based on the messages it shows.

Comment: B, Is there a way to set the apache module to not change those specific lines? so that I can use only the file_line resource to control those lines

Answer (score 0):

I used the same code to  test in my  setup ,there is no replacement happening after the first run, same with  the refresh too.I suspect the refresh would be the  outcome of some other code snippet.